# How to move back 1000 line while reading and looping through a big file in BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am reading and looping a big file using `BufferedReader` in java. I want to ask if there is a way that I can move 1000 lines behind in the loop? It is a simple CSV file and I am saving all records in a String in each loop.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\file.txt"));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {  
    // normal processing
    if (condition)
    // move 1000 lines back again in the loop above (i.e. re-read 1000 lines again)

}
```

Is there any way I can move back?

Comment: Generally speaking, if you gain access at the buffer level you can re-read prior buffers and count lines going backwards.  You'd probably have to write your own BufferedReader replacement, though, to gain buffer access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mark()` and `reset(),` provided the buffer is big enough, or you could maintain the most recent 1000 lines in a deque, but why? Re-reading files is just a sign of bad design. Most files can be read left to right in a single pass. Compilers do it: so can you.

Comment: Thanks EJP, mark() takes intReadAhead parameter, which I don't understand. It simply hangs if I put say 1000. And also it does not reset back to the proper position.

Comment: The parameter is just what it says in the Javadoc: the number of characters you want to be able to read while still retaining the mark. It's not a line count. The 'hang' and the rest of it are hard to believe. Are you sure there is no exception?

Comment: What if Im not sure about the number of Characters ?

Comment: Then overspecify it, but I repeat that you shouldn't have to do this at all.